# What "rules of thumb" preprocessing techniques to use for neural nets?

Tags: neural-networks, python, data-preprocessing

Usually when we have an algorithm, we have some rules regarding what kind of data preprocessing techniques that algorithm needs. For example LinearRegression has the following rules:

1. There must be a linear relationship between features and target.
2. Residuals should have a Normal distribution plot.
3. The residuals are independent.
4. Linear Regression works well with Normally distributed data so we use transformation techniques (log transform etc) on the features to get a Normal distribution.
5. Scaling is required
6. Sensitive to outliers so need to treat them.

Similarly there are rules for every algorithm. So my question is that are there any similar rules/assumptions for Neural Nets? Since Linear Regression and Neural Nets both work on the same logic (gradient descent), do the same rules apply to neural nets?

One rule I know about is that the data needs to be scaled before feeding in the neural network. I would love some input from you stalwarts.

**EDIT 1:** Ok I think my question is not clear enough. What I want is a list of must do preprocessing techniques for a neural net just like we have one for algorithms like linear regression, knn etc. I gave the example of linear regression **just as an example**. It could be any other algorithm.

Thank you!

Comment: The target does not need to be normally distributed in a linear regression. When we make a normality assumption in a linear regression, we make it about the conditional distribution, not the marginal (pooled) distribution of all observations of $y$.

Comment: Yes my bad! Edited

Comment: How do you figure that linear regression uses gradient descent?

Comment: Link to an article  https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/04/gradient-descent-in-linear-regression/

Comment: Your regression example remains contentious and is a distraction from your question. The residuals can't be independent (any ideal condition there concerns the errors); the main reason for transformation is in my view to get closer to linearity, not to make any distribution more nearly normal; I've not worried about scaling for some decades....

Comment: @NickCox Log transformation can change the distribution of a variable from skewed to normal and don't normal distribution makes the algorithm converge more faster?

Comment: I do know that logarithmic transformation can be useful. Since Legendre and Gauss we have least squares, so I don't follow what algorithm you have in mind to converge slowly or rapidly.

Comment: Any algorithm that uses gradient descent should converge rapidly if the variables are normally distributed. Atleast that is what I think. I may be wrong though.

Comment: As @Dave implied, I think, plain or vanilla linear regression doesn't need gradient descent.

Comment: @NickCox See my updated question

Comment: I have seen examples where gradient descent is used to calculate the parameters of a linear regression and verify that you get the same answer as the usual $\hat\beta_{ols} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$, but those have always been introductions to gradient descent that will be used in regression models that do not have analytic solutions to the parameter estimates. // I might want to split the assumptions into theoretical and computational, where a computational assumption would perhaps be something that affects convergence but not the true argmin.

Comment: The old comp.ai.neural-nets FAQ has lots of useful guidance on a variety of topics.  http://www.faqs.org/faqs/ai-faq/neural-nets/part1/preamble.html

Comment: I don't think the residuals *need* to be normally distributed.  It depends what you want to do.  AIUI, the output of the model will still be an estimate of the conditional mean of the target distribution even if the residuals are non-normal.  I don't really agree with lists  of "must do" steps as it tends to limit the things you can do, and it encourages people to use these steps without understanding what they are doing (or questioning whether they are useful, e.g. balancing unbalanced datasets).